# MFC Add Tooltip for disabled radio button

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

In MFC (old I know), I am trying to add a Tooltip that appears only when a radio button is disabled.

I am able to show the tooltip with code such as:

```
m_ToolTip.Create(this);
m_ToolTip.AddTool(GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIOBUTTON), "Tooltip text");
m_ToolTip.Activate(TRUE);
```

But it does not work when my radio button is disabled, (apparently that is by design)

After some research it appears that I need to override the

```
PreTranslateMessage()
```

function to get the ToolTip showing, perhaps tracking when the mouse enters into the control area, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Since the window is disabled, you are not going to be able to use tooltips with it. However, you can use GetWindowRect(), translate to a client area rectangle on the dialog, and then add a tool for the space that the window occupies. Look at overrides for CToolTipCtrl::AddTool that take RECT arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL MyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // GF: Fix tooltips on disabled items.
    m_wndCtrl.RelayEvent(pMsg->message, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);
    m_wndCtrl.UpdateWindow();
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you explained, what the core issue is, and how this answer addresses it. Besides, I couldn't find a single MFC class that exposes a public `RelayEvent` member with the signature you are using. But then, it's also unclear, what `m_wndCtrl` is.

Comment: Oh dear. The m_wndCtrl is a control derived from CButton or CEdit..., that has a CToolTipCtrl m_toolTip member and this implementation:


     void ThisClass::RelayEvent(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
      if (m_tooltip.m_hWnd != NULL)
      {
       MSG msg;
       msg.hwnd= m_hWnd; msg.message= message; msg.wParam= wParam; msg.lParam= lParam; msg.time= 0; msg.pt.x= LOWORD (lParam); msg.pt.y= HIWORD (lParam);
       m_tooltip.RelayEvent(&msg);
      }
     }